# SQL SELECT: "Give me all documents where all of the documents procedures are 'work in progress'"

Tags: sql, mysql

This one really has me stumped.  I have a documents table which hold info about the documents, and a procedures table, which is kind of like a revisions table for each document.  What I need to do is write a select statement which gives me all of the documents where all of the procedures have the status "work_in_progress".  Here's an example

procedures table:

```
document_id | status
1           | 'wip' 
1           | 'wip'
1           | 'wip'
1           | 'approved'
2           | 'wip'
2           | 'wip'
2           | 'wip'
```

Here, I would want my query to only return document id 2, because all of its statuses are work_in_progress. I DO NOT want document_id 1 since one of its statuses is 'approved'.  I believe this is relational division I want, but I'm not sure where to start.  This is MySQL 5.0 FYI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this as:

```
SELECT document_id, document_name, ...
FROM documents AS d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT document_id
                  FROM procedures
                  WHERE document_id = d.document_id
                      AND status != 'wip');
```

That is, "show me all documents where there aren't any rows in procedures with a status other than 'wip'".

So it's coming at it a little sideways from the way you described it. Instead of "all the rows are 'wip'", you verify that there aren't any rows that *are not* 'wip'.

Comment: Posted some 'benchmarks' on working solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673053/sql-select-give-me-all-documents-where-all-of-the-documents-procedures-are-wor/2673480#2673480. Your's is on top :)

Answer (score 2):

My preferred method would be this, as it uses a count to check the number that are wip is the same as the number in total

```
SELECT
    document_id
FROM
    documents
GROUP BY
    document_id
HAVING
    COUNT(*) =
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(*)
    FROM
        documents documents2
    WHERE
        documents2.status = 'wip'
     AND
        documents2.document_id = documents.document_id
)
```

Comment: Can't you also do something like `HAVING EVERY(status = 'wip')`?

Comment: There's no `EVERY()` aggregate function.  You could do `HAVING MIN(status) = MAX(status) = 'wip'`.

Comment: I like the MIN = MAX, very nice, although I usually like to avoid aggregates on strings. I also still prefer using the COUNT as I have though as it "reads" more like the question was asked.

Comment: @Mark, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673053/sql-select-give-me-all-documents-where-all-of-the-documents-procedures-are-wor/2673480#2673480 - for having every you can either use also 'where value = all ( subquery )' or do mysql specific bit_and(field='value') which will aggregate the condition

Comment: I am not sure the count should be preferred in a general situation: it forces the database to actually do the counts on both sides - outside aggregate and the correlated subquery; in case of EXISTS/ALL subqueries it is possible to determine if a row is part of the result without examining all the rows of the subquery (on average; worst case scenario would look at all rows).

Answer (score 2):

Here's one more version of the same thing

```
SELECT document_id, document_name
FROM documents d 
WHERE 'wip' = ALL(SELECT status 
                  FROM procedures p 
                  WHERE p.document_id = d.document_id);
```

And another one

```
SELECT document_id, document_name
FROM documents d
     INNER JOIN procedures p ON d.document_id = p.document_id
GROUP BY document_id
HAVING bit_and(p.status='wip')
```

EDIT:
I wondered how do the working solutions compare to each other in terms of performance, so I tested with ~300k records in procedures and ~15k records in documents with minimum number of columns and indexes covering only document_id on modest hardware

1. [NOT EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673053/sql-select-give-me-all-documents-where-all-of-the-documents-procedures-are-wor/2673085#2673085) ~1.2s
2. 'wip' = ALL () ~1.2s
3. [HAVING COUNT(*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673053/sql-select-give-me-all-documents-where-all-of-the-documents-procedures-are-wor/2673102#2673102) ~2.5s
4. bit_and() ~2.5s

so it seems that bit_and() does not optimize so well as it could.
Also a note, adding index on (document_id, status) half the times presented above.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT document_name FROM documents WHERE 'approved' NOT IN (SELECT status FROM procedures WHERE procedures.document_id = documents.document_id)`

Comment: This ALMOST has me there.  The problem with this approach is that I don't want to always know all of the statuses.  I could probably get by for now by just keeping track of all of the different status.  I also have inactive, approval_pending, etc.  How do I incorporate those into this query.  THANKS!

Comment: So you only want the ones with only the same type of status? I.e documents that *only* have EITHER wip/approved/inactive/approval_pending etc? Or do you want to select them based on a variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT document_id FROM documents WHERE document_id NOT IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT document_id FROM procedures WHERE status != 'wip')
```